# is openssl 1.0.1 supported in php 5.3.2?

Tags: php, openssl, tls1.2

I need to upgrade openssl version from 0.9.8 to 1.0.1 or higher in ubuntu server in order to support TLS 1.2. I am using php 5.3.2 in ubuntu 4.22.

Upgrading openssl have any dependency on PHP version?

What is the relationship between php version and openssl version?

Comment: I did. But so can i assume any version of openssl >=0.9.6 can be installed in any version of php >=4.3.2 at all the times(the php.net link you mentioned is posted 7 years ago)? If i ask that question directly that would not make sense. so just made it in this way. :) Thanks. Assuming this as correct answer i am gonna proceed upgrading openssl :)